# Почему не создается индекс для одного из столбцов в связующей таблице(связь многие ко многим)?

Tags: entity-framework-core, миграция, entity-framework-6

Есть проект в котором используется entity framework 6, пытаюсь мигрировать на entity framework core, возникла проблема что создаваемая бд отличается от уже существующей. Пример

```
public class User: IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Handbook> Units {get;set;} = new List<Handbook>();
}

public class Handbook
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;} = new List<User>();
}
```

Связь многие ко многим настраивалась так

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Units)
    .WithMany(x => x.Users)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        x.MapRightKey("UnitId");
        x.ToTable("UserUnits");
    });
```

ef 6 генерировал следующую скрипт создания таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserUnits (
  UserId INT NOT NULL
 ,UnitId INT NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserUnits] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId, UnitId)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_UnitId
ON dbo.UserUnits (UnitId)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_UserId
ON dbo.UserUnits (UserId)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.UserUnits
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserUnits_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES dbo.AspNetUsers (Id)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.UserUnits
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserUnits_dbo.Handbooks_UnitId] FOREIGN KEY (UnitId) REFERENCES dbo.Handbooks (Id)
GO
```

в ef core связь многие ко многим настроил следующим образом

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Units)
    .WithMany(x => x.Users)
    .UsingEntity(
        "UserUnits",
            l => l.HasOne(typeof(Handbook)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("UnitId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Handbook.Id)).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
            r => r.HasOne(typeof(User)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(User.Id)).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
            j => j.HasKey("UserId", "UnitId")
     );
```

ef core сгенерировал следующий скрипт создания таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserUnits (
  UserId INT NOT NULL
 ,UnitId INT NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_UserUnits PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId, UnitId)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_UserUnits_UnitId
ON dbo.UserUnits (UnitId)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.UserUnits
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserUnits_Handbooks_UnitId FOREIGN KEY (UnitId) REFERENCES dbo.Handbooks (Id)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.UserUnits
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserUnits_Users_UserId FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES dbo.Users (Id)
GO
```

По какой то причине ef core не создает индекс для поля UserId, я конечно могу в генерируемый скрипт миграции в ручную добавить создание индекса для нужного мне поля

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(name: "IX_UserUnits_UserId",table: "UserUnits",column: "UserId");
```

но этот вариант считаю крайним средством, которого хотелось бы избежать из чего возникает следующий вопрос, как *заставить* ef core создать отсутствующий индекс?

p.s. Знаю вариант про вариант создания промежуточной таблицы через создание UserUnit класса, но по ряду причин его хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: *По какой то причине ef core не создает индекс для поля UserId* Может, по причине его ненужности? ибо `UserId`  является префиксом первичного индекса..

Comment: @Akina А почему для UnitId создается индекс?

Comment: А потому что это поле НЕ является префиксом другого индекса.

Comment: Кстати... а как соотносится в системе (ну приблизительно) количество различных UserId и UnitId? Если вторых заметно больше, то имеет смысл "перевернуть" первичный индекс..

Comment: @Akina в данной связующей таблице всего 14 строк, так как программа находится в эксплуатации я бы хотел мигрировать бд с минимальными изменениями,  так как сравниваю было стало через сравнение схем бд

Comment: @Akina посмотрел данные: 1 пользователь 1 подразделение, 1 подразделении до 10 пользователей.

Comment: Ааа, ну на такой мелкой таблице пофиг. Там и индексы-то нафиг не нужны в общем.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ответы, это все только для того что бы обеспечить минимальное изменение вновь создаваемой бд на этапе миграции